# how would I turn this dynamic CSS dot graph into a line graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a dot graph with CSS that uses JavaScript to do all the calculations ect ect

The graph will be used for many things, including site analysis.

I allow users to activate a real time function that updates the graph automatically every x seconds.

The graph uses a series of AJAX requests to fetch data from databases, so i cant show an example of the exact thing.

But I have put together this one in JSFiddle, which only includes some random percentages for the graph to work on:

http://jsfiddle.net/57Jjd/1/

I was wondering if there is any way I could possibly turn this into a line graph, that animates along with the spots on `update()`, preferably using just CSS, JavaScript and Jquery?

So instead of:

[image]

I'd like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using simple Divs and to get a continuous line you should interpolate your points (divs). I suggest you using HTML5 (canvas) because interpolating many divs (many as the resolution of your graph) could make your page hard to render.
HTML5 canvas is of course what you need if you want interpolation between points.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? (100 - top = height)

```
$("#spot_1").animate({
    top: "95%",
    height: "5%"
});
```

Comment: Yeah. I had that sorted in the actual graph, but didn't implement it in the fiddle. Sorry.